# move_uploaded_file(); not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

I've just written a script to upload images and i've checked it for a long but I can't find where is the error. The entire code do what it's supposed to do but the move_uploaded_file(); function doesn't. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" id="img-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Subir imagen: <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
<div id="respuesta"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
$("input[name='file']").on("change", function(){
var formData = new FormData($("#img-form")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/uploadimage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
       {
         $("#respuesta").html(data);
       }
    });
 });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require '../init.php';

if (isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES["file"];
    $nombre = $file["name"];
    $type = $file["type"];
    $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"];
    $size = $file["size"];
    $gethandw = getimagesize($ruta_provisional);
    $width = $gethandw[0];
    $height = $gethandw[1];
    $path = "img/users/";

    if ($type != 'image/jpg' && $type != 'image/jpeg' && $type != 'image/png' && $type != 'image/gif')
    {
      echo "Error, el archivo no es una imagen"; 
    }
    else if ($size > 1024*1024)
    {
      echo "Error, el tamaño máximo permitido es un 1MB";
    }
    else if ($width > 400 || $height > 400)
    {
        echo "Error la anchura y la altura maxima permitida es 500px";
    }
    else if($width < 60 || $height < 60)
    {
        echo "Error la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es 60px";
    }
    else
    {
        $src = $path.$nombre;
        move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);
        echo "<img src='$src'>";
    }
}
```

The answer (data) outputs everything correct but the image is not uploading anywhere, I'm using xampp for testing

Comment: I can not see any error. Are you sure it is not uploaded? Check img/users/ directory

Comment: Does your web server have write access to `img/users` directory?

Comment: You can try with this: if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))

Comment: what does error reporting throw back, the error number on the uploading and the developer console?

Comment: how do i know if my web server has access to that path @MartinHeralecký

Comment: Are you having a Control Panel with filemanager? Because in filemanager you can usually see permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code seems ok. I found some issues with your implementation of FormData. Please try the below code

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='file']").on("change", function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $(this)[0].files[0]); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/uploadimage.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#respuesta").html(data);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

Please let me know if you are still facing difficulties. Hope this helps.Thanks

Comment: Still happens the same